# Confused about accessing content of binary tree node with pointer

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree

If I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct node
{
  int key_value;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
};
```

And I have a search function that looks like this:

```
struct node *search(int key, struct node *leaf)
{
  if( leaf != 0 )
  {
      if(key==leaf->key_value)
      {
          return leaf;
      }
      else if(key<leaf->key_value)
      {
          return search(key, leaf->left);
      }
      else
      {
          return search(key, leaf->right);
      }
  }
  else return 0;
}
```

Why inside the search function, when comparing the value with a leaf, instead of doing:

```
key < (*leaf)->key_value
```

is done `key < leaf->key_value`

Isn't leaf a pointer? So we first need to dereference the pointer and then access the value?

So, we are passing an address to the function, and we should first get the content that is pointed to that address, and then get the value (key_value) right?

Comment: `->` does a dereference...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pointer is being dereferenced. leaf->key_value is equivalent to (*leaf).key_value. The arrow operator implies dereferencing of the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`leaf` is alredy a pointer (you can see it by observing parameters of your function) and a pointer, as the word itself says, will point directly to the right memory area.

`->` operator will dereference it, allowing you to access stored value